# UNIQUE KEY generated from nowhere

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 tables with *@ManyToMany* relation field. In hibernate cfg i have

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Table which is created during application startup has *UNIQUE* key set on *PartId* column, which is

```
@JoinColumn(name="PartId")}
```

in *@ManyToMany* relation. I didn't set anywhere that this column should have unique key. Is this the default auto creation behaviour?

The DB is **MySQL 5.5**

Thanks.

**UPD:**

Full field desc is:

```
@ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="Part_Dev", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PartId")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="DevCode")})
    public List<Dom> getDom() { return dom; }
```

**UPD 2**

sorry, I see I didn't mention it. Unique key in *Parts* table,

```
@Entity @Table(name="Parts") 
public class Parts implements Serializable{ 

@ManyToMany 
 @JoinTable(name="Part_Dev", 
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PartId")}, 
  inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="DevCode")}) 
public List<Dom> getDom() { 
  return dom; }

  @Column(name="PartId")
public Integer getPartId() {
  return partId; }
```

Comment: @JoinColumn(name="PartId") specifies the field in "Part_Dev", and by default should point it to the primary key field in Parts.  You haven't shown the ID in Parts, or any other mappings/annotations that might show why "PartId" in Parts gets generated with the Unique key setting.

Comment: If PartsId is the pk of Parts, it needs to be unique otherwise there would be no way to tell different Parts instances apart.

Comment: Yeah, though of it myself. Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Chris told, that was the way to identify each part.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify @JoinTable to make it happen. For instance, if you have two entities : Employee and Project in a many-to-many relationship. You need to have @JoinTable on one side.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id private int id;
private String name;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="EMP_PROJ",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID"))
private Collection<Project> projects;
```

Comment: I have *@JoinTable* in my code. Tables are generated and application is deployed OK. The question is - why unique key is generated when I explicitly didn't ask for it.

Comment: in which table **PartId** is unique? it is primary key of the entity from owning side of relationship. it shouldn't be unique in join table.